# Is a CSRF required if no direct state change operations are performed?

Tags: csrf, header

I'm currently developing a webservice that sits in between other webservices. In the process of securing this webservice I've gotten a bit stuck on whether or not we neeed to require a CSRF token on its endpoints. This webservice does not directly interact with any database or persistent information so we are not performing any state changes. However, it does send a request to another webservice that does make changes to a database. This other webservice that makes changes is already protected by a CSRF requirement and my webservice just forwards cookie/header information.

In this situation does my webservice need CSRF protection, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: CSRF takes advantage of an authenticated state and abuses the fact that any requests from the authenticated browser will carry the authentication. Does your service require users to authenticate with it directly?

Answer (score 1):

### CSRF for Proxies

It sounds like your service is acting more or less as a proxy for other services.  Looking at things from that perspective I would say that the preference is to **not** perform CSRF protection (which is a stronger statement than suggesting that CSRF protection may not be necessary).

The reason is that if you are not doing anything yourself but *transparently* forwarding requests for someone else, then attempting to provide a security measure where none is expected/required will cause headaches for the person you are providing this proxy service for.  In other words, you've increased cost/usability without necessarily increasing security, which is a bad trade off.

In short, unilaterally dropping in security checks everywhere isn't often a good idea.  Unless you know for sure which requests require a CSRF check and which requests don't, you're probably better off letting the user's who operate the actual endpoints decide for themselves if CSRF is required.  Of course if you know for sure when CSRF should or should not be required, then it may not hurt to put it in as an additional safeguard, just in case someone on the other end forgets it.

Presuming you opt to skip out on CSRF protection on your end, it may be worth noting this fact in documentation somewhere. After all, it may not occur to the people using the service that they can and should implement the usual security measures when needed by their own system.